# InstallShield - How to run installer using custom actions (VB script)

Tags: vb.net, matlab, installshield-le

I have a package which binds my product and MATLAB run time as a dependency. The dependency should be installed only if its not present in target machine. I have selected deferred execution of a VB script (It should fire after File transfer).

Here's the code:

```
public function MatlabCheck()

Dim MATLABVal 
MATLABVal = Session.property("MATLABROOT")

If Len(MATLABVal) = 0 Then
   Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
   Dim cmd
   cmd = Session.Property("INSTALLDIR\v1.0\dependencies\MCR_R2013b_win32_installer.exe")
   objShell.run cmd
end if

end function
```

Note that I have put `MATLABROOT` property under Additional Requirements.

Using InstallShield Limited Edition on VS 2013.

I tried running this setup with the script integrated, however, it didn't work.

Comment: It looks like you're using Session.Property correctly on line 4 above. But not on the line where you're setting the cmd variable.

It should be:
var = Session.Property("PROPERTYNAME")

Comment: Alright, so if I were to just use `INSTALLDIR` then concatenate with rest of the path while executing like this: `cmd = Session.Property("INSTALLDIR")
 objShell.run cmd & "v1.0\dependencies\MCR_R2013b_win32_installer.exe"`, it should work right?

Comment: In theory, yes. You'll want to surround the path in quotes to be sure it can handle spaces in the path. Also, typically the INSTALLDIR property is where your application is being installed to. My guess based on your complete path is that you may want to investigate the SOURCEDIR property.